# Tool type icon with text in Extjs Panel

Tags: extjs

How do I add a text beside the icon in Extjs Panel tool type?

Example:
Below code displays print icon at top right corner of the Panel.

```
tools : [
    {
         type: 'print',
         // text : 'Print document',
         handler : function(){

             Ext.Msg.alert('print', 'you clicked print icon');
         }
    }    
]
```

I like it to render it as ["print icon" space "Print document"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a config  `iconAlign : String  possible inputs are`'top'
'right'
'bottom'
'left'`

Comment: I don't understand why is this accepted answer? How can `iconAling` add text there? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you please check the documentation. We can position the image in the button along with text using the above config

Comment: The question is about "tool type icon with text" `xtype: tool` doesn't have any text config http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Tool.html the position of the icon is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry mate we have a conflict may be because of me . I would have answered it more clearly. Keeping your answer in my mind just suggested iconAlign can move button to any postion . I just refered you to documentation for button not tool dont take it in offesenive.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can write a text to a tool (well you could "hack" it using CSS). But you can create custom [header](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-header) for your panel and put a button there.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mypanel',

    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    header: {
        title: 'My Panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Print Document',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-print'
        }]
    }

});
```

[image: the panel image]

Working fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qit